# F# exception filters

Tags: exception, f#, clr

The article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-good-and-the-bad-of-exception-filters/ suggests that F# natively supports exception filters (that have no syntax in C#, for instance). Exception filters run *before* the appropriate catch block and if they return true, the catch block will execute. I would imagine F# does this using something like this

```
with
    | ex when filter(ex) -> printfn "Caught"
```

However, for me it compiles to the usual "catch [mscorlib]System.Object" with a call to the filter function inside the catch block and no "filter" section is present in generated MSIL. So the question is, does F# really support this construct?

Thanks

Comment: Why do the internals of the way this is implemented matter to you?

Comment: @JohnPalmer - the implementation strategy actually effects the semantics in some corner cases (due to .NET/Windows's two pass model), so I think it's a pretty relevant question.

Comment: VB.NET and F# have similar conditional catch constructs, however, VB.NET compiler emits _filter_ blocks and F# apparently does not. This makes the semantics matter, as @kvb has put it, in some cases, especially with interop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, F# does not actually implement/use/expose the `filter` handlers available in MSIL (*ECMA-335, 5th ed., Partition I, Section 12.4.2 "Exception handling"*). According to section 6.9.21 of the [F# 3.0 language specification](http://fsharp.org/about/files/spec.pdf), the compiler is supposed to compile the entire `with` clause into a `catch` block; a "fall-through" case is added to the compiled code so that if the caught exception does not match any of the patterns in the `with` clause, it is re-raised (via the `rethrow` IL instruction).

That said, I'd really like to see F# support more low-level IL/CLR constructs -- they aren't used often, but sometimes they provide the only way to implement something correctly, or they avoid the need for complicated workarounds; and, as in the OP's case, it's important that F# supports these for purposes of interoperability. For example, `try...fault` would really be handy for logging purposes, and it would simplify some bits of code which currently need to use `try...finally` with additional logic (e.g., the implementation of `lock` in `FSharp.Core`).

UPDATE: I was just searching around for information on a completely different topic, and ran across this post from 2006 on Don's blog: [F# 1.1.13 now available!](http://web.archive.org/web/20130623040356/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2006/11/30/f-1-1-13-now-available.aspx) (also see the accompanying [release notes](http://web.archive.org/web/20080725214837/http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2006/11/30/f-1-1-13-detailed-release-notes.aspx)). Of course, F# 1.1.13 was a *very* early version of the language, and it was still quite experimental at that point, but is interesting to see that the compiler once had a `--generate-filter-blocks` switch.